# SQL - daily water consumption. Difference between days

Tags: sql, extract

I have to do some task about a daily water consumption. I have, in a database, water readings from every hour and every day. I need somehow to extract the total amount of a daily consumption. What I have now:

Timestamp                Consumption
**2013-07-28 00:00:32    143.720**
2013-07-28 01:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 02:00:32    143.720
2013-07-28 03:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 04:00:36    143.720
2013-07-28 05:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 06:00:32    143.720
2013-07-28 07:00:32    143.720
2013-07-28 08:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 09:00:32    143.720
2013-07-28 10:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 11:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 12:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 13:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 14:00:32    143.720
2013-07-28 15:00:31    143.720
2013-07-28 16:00:32    143.730
2013-07-28 17:00:31    143.730
2013-07-28 18:00:31    143.730
2013-07-28 19:00:31    143.780
2013-07-28 20:00:31    143.820
2013-07-28 21:00:32    143.820
2013-07-28 22:00:31    143.820
2013-07-28 23:00:32    143.820
**2013-07-29 00:00:31    143.820**
2013-07-29 01:00:32    143.820
2013-07-29 02:00:31    143.820
2013-07-29 03:00:32    143.820
2013-07-29 04:00:31    143.850
2013-07-29 05:00:32    143.850
**2013-07-29 06:00:31    143.850**

[a piece of my data]

So basically, I need to take one record of each day and subtract the values with the value of the next day and so on...

---

E.g.

**2013-07-28 00:00:32   143,720**

**2013-07-29 00:00:31   143,820**

**2013-07-29 06:00:31   143,850**

Abs(143,720 - 143,820) = **0,100**

Abs(143,820 - 143,850) = **0,030**

---

I would like output to be:

DATE  CONSUMPTION

2013-07-28   **0,100**

2013-07-29   **0,030**

So it is the difference in water consumption every day

My current code(to obtain this piece of data that I mentioned about):

```
SELECT water.timeStamp, water.volume1
FROM water
INNER JOIN meter
ON water.meterId=meter.id and water.timeStamp between date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -31 DAY) and curdate()
INNER JOIN usercustomer
ON meter.customerId = usercustomer.customerId
INNER JOIN user
ON usercustomer.userId=user.id AND user.username LIKE 'user' AND user.password LIKE 'pass'
ORDER BY water.timeStamp ASC;
```

//Sometimes there would be less than 24 readings per day and it could be not in the same minute

***EDIT***
Also I would like to have the consumption of current day even if the day is not finished. E.g. If there are readings from 00-06 I would like to show them.
For now here is an example with null instead of water usage of the very last day http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/979c1/1

Comment: Given your Edit - See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/979c1/5

Comment: Unfortunately if this example is based on Meter Readings none of the Answers take into account what happens when the meter clocks over which inevitably all of them do... once you get into this territory you have to code in no of dials and simply selection a min & max will not help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  Readings.dte as day, 
  PrevReadings.dte as prevday, 
  Readings.StartReading - PrevReadings.StartReading as consumption from 
(
  select Date(ReadDate) as dte, Min(Consumption) as StartReading 
  from meter_readings
  Group By Date(ReadDate)
) as Readings
left join
(
  select Date(ReadDate)as dte, Min(Consumption)  as StartReading
  from meter_readings
  Group By Date(ReadDate)
) as PrevReadings
on PrevReadings.dte = Readings.dte - 1
```

I have assumed that it is sufficient for your purposes to compare the opening reading for each day to calculate the daily consumption.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/819d1/9

Hope that helps

Edit - I have added an alternative that might clarify some points

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/819d1/11

Your edit introduces a new requirement which may be resolved with the following Sql

```
    SELECT Readings.dte AS day,
       Ifnull(NextReadings.reading, (SELECT Max(consumption)
                                     FROM   meter_readings)) - Readings.reading AS Consumption
FROM   (SELECT Date(readdate)   AS dte,
               Min(consumption) AS Reading
        FROM   meter_readings
        GROUP  BY Date(readdate)) AS Readings
     LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT Date(readdate)   AS dte,
               Min(consumption) AS Reading
        FROM   meter_readings
        GROUP  BY Date(readdate)) AS NextReadings
     ON NextReadings.dte = Readings.dte + 1
```

Comment: There is a problem when the current day is 2013-08-01 and the previous should be 2013-07-31. The prevday is null *(PrevReadings.dte = Readings.dte - 1)*

Comment: Ok I have found the solution. It should be like *PrevReadings.dte = date_add(Readings.dte, INTERVAL -1 DAY);* Thank you very much

Comment: You slightly missed my point, then.  The reason I put 2 dates in the query was to illustrate the issue.  The query gives you exactly what you want it just gives you a choice - 'Prevday' could be called 'OnDay' Day could be called 'UpToDay'.

Comment: The null is correct - you need a full day's data to make the calculation.

Comment: But is there a way to show current day even if it isn't finished, I mean only with a few readings. I need to show the consumption of a today. Any hints how to sovle this problem?

Comment: Change the Min() functions in the Query to Max() - that will move the logic on by 24 hours for days where you have full data. This was really my point in including both dates in fiddle #9. Once again you will not be able to calculate a value with no previous day reading.

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/819d1/14.  Note that we no longer have a value for 28th, because there is no closing reading for 27th.  Consumption really is zero for 29th, given the small data sample.

Comment: Well, it is not a proper solution ;(. Typically, this is read from 23 to 23 the next day. And it ignores the hour of the day from 23 to 00, and taking this hour from the previous one.

Comment: You are missing the point.  You have to make a judgement as to which day the consumption at 00:00:32 belongs to.  Beyond that I cannot help you.

Comment: I have to present this data on daily chart and day starts at 00. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @user2725105 - ok, but do not get too complacent - there is still a number of questions you need to answer in your own mind as to how this will behave.  Try testing on some data where there is only one reading in a day, and where the data is missing for a day.  You also might need to consider how this will behave when the meter 'rolls over' from 99999 to 000000 - etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

since the consumption is never going to decrease (hour to next hour), can you not take

```
MAX(consumption) - MIN(consumption)
```

for each date?

**Update**:

You may have to do

```
MIN(consumption_today) - MIN(consumption_yesterday)
```

to include and account for all consumption that happened between last reading of yesterday and first reading of today.

Comment: I was trying to do so but there is a problem. If there is a reading between 23 and 00

Comment: as long as date remains  unchanged, it shouldn't matter. you should [convert "timestamp" to "date"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp) and then probably do "group by date"

Comment: e.g. 2013-07-28 00:00:32 -- 0.420 <----MIN of the Day 1 **** 2013-07-28 23:00:32 -- 0.520 <----MAX of the Day 1 ************ 2013-07-29 00:00:32 -- 0.600 <----MIN of the Day 2 **** 2013-07-29 23:00:32 -- 0.640 <----MAX of the Day 2. So consumption DAY1: 0.100; DAY2: 0.040 +++++++++++ BUT what about 0.600-0.520 = 0.080 it is gone

Comment: The calculation needs to be min_of_day - min_of_previous_day, otherwise you miss out on overnight consumption, I think.

Comment: Looking at the sample data I wrongly assumed Max(day) is same as Min(day+1). If that is not the case, you have to use [Min(day+1) - Min(day)] as suggested by @HughJones. But writing a **single** query for this is going to be somewhat tricky.